# Selecting From Database Using 2 variables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, laravel

What I am trying to achieve is fetching data from database using a select  inside another select. I succeed importing the `sender = $id`, however I want to return records where both:

- `sender = $id && receiver = any user`
- `receiver = $id && sender = any user`

This is my code:

```
$comments = \DB::select('select * from
                           (select * from comments c
                               where `sender` = ?     //(here) 
                               order by created_at desc) am
                           group by conversation_id
                           order by created_at desc
                           LIMIT 10',
                           [\Auth::user()->id]);
```

---

Using these would result in errors:

```
where ? = (sender, receiver)
```

> `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'sender, receiver)`

```
where ? = (`sender`, `receiver`)

SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 1
column(s) (SQL: select * from (select * from comments m
where Test = (`from`, `to`)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where the sender or receiver = the user id

```
where ? in (sender,receiver)
```

Comment: No need to change the `in` to `=`